# semi-continuity of a function on $H_0^1(\Omega) $ with respect to the weak topology

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> In the sobolev space $H_0^1(\Omega)$, prove that  the function $$
> h(v)=\frac12||\nabla v||_2^2-\int_\Omega f(x)v(x)dx
> $$ is semi-countineous with respect to the weak topology, where $f\in L^2(\Omega)$, $v\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ and $\Omega$ is a connected domain.

---

(I found it in  a Dirichlet problem in sobolev spaces. )

Answer (score 0):

To show that $h$ is weakly lower-semicontinuous, it is sufficient to show that it is continuous and convex.

(If you do not know the theorem "continous $+$ convex $\Rightarrow$ weakly lower-semicontinuous", then look at the epigraph of $h$).

Comment: weakly lower-semicontinuous !! i think that this is the problem for me, waht does it mean the countinuity with respect to the weak topology of a sobolev space or if you can fo a normed space in general (i know the notion of the weak convergence but not the weak continuity)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity

Comment: thank you for unswering :) but my problem is the WEAK continuity (i mean when it is the cas of "the weak topology")

Comment: for example if it is the case of the normal semi-continuity i can prove it but when it the case of th weak semi-continuity (or continuity in general) i don t know how to do that or what is the definition ..... i searched every where

Comment: I do not see where your problem is. In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity#Formal_definition you find the definition. Apply it to your normed space equipped with the weak topology.

Comment: yeah exactly , my space here is $H_0^1$ how aplly it here, and what is the weak topology of this sobolev space, i know the general definition of the weak topology (generated by the $f^{-1}(U)$, U is an open ........  but in this space is not really clear, .......